# Convert a SVG to PNG react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, canvas, png

I've an SVG image that includes two PNG images that makes them one SVG image, now I want to convert this image into PNG/JPG. I've the following code of SVG in react:

```
import P1 from "../../assets/P1.png";
import P2 from "../../assets/P2.png";
```

```
<canvas id="imageCanvas" width="321" height="469"></canvas>
<img id="imageR"  ></img>
<svg id="imageCard" name="imageCard" width="321" height="469" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <image href={P2} width="321" height="469" />
     <image href={P1} x="93" y="151" width="48" height="48" />
</svg>
```

It showing the proper result in the browser, now I want to convert this svg image to PNG/JPG format, I've tried an solution to convert this image to canvas first and then to PNG:

```
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
var img = document.querySelector('#imageR');
var canvas = document.querySelector('#imageCanvas');

// get svg data
var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);

// make it base64
var svg64 = btoa(xml);
var b64Start = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64;charset=utf-8,';

// prepend a "header"
var image64 = b64Start + svg64;

// set it as the source of the img element
img.onload = function () {
      // draw the image onto the canvas
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
ImageBase64 = image64;

img.src = image64;
```

but it is not work properly, it only works if I don't use image tag inside the SVG, please guide me, thank you.

Comment: if all you need to draw is some images why not load and draw them directly to the canvas?  ... my guess is that the actual problem is that the images have not fully loaded when you get the onload for the svg

Comment: @HelderSepulveda, Actually I need a large size image (930 X 1407 or more) but I want to show on screen of (321 X 469), and to download canvas as image, it must be shown on screen. On other side, SVG can be downloaded even if it is displayed none. By the way, thank you, the canvas worked for me by showing it on a separate/extra page.